Can I use Notepad++ to remove line breaks from strings and keep things neat?
I'm working on translating an old game. I have the strings displayed/organized like this
This is a
sentence that you
really need to read.<End>



This is also a
sentence that you
need to read.<End>

Is there a way to use N++'s expresions to turn the above into something like this?
This is a sentence that you really need to read.<End>



This is also a sentence that you need to read.<End>

Since this is Japanese, I don't necessarily need to add a space. It's more about joining and making one "line".
TIA
I was looking over the manual I tried the usual "\n[[:alnum:]]" then "$&" but I'm totally lost.

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:
Find:    \R(?=\S)
Replace: (single space)

This regex matches \R, which is a system-agnostic line ending (i.e. matches CRLF on Windows and LF on Unix).  The lookahead (?=\S) asserts that what follows is the start of another line containing text.  This preserves the line breaks which are separating the blocks of text.

Sorry for the late reply, but thank you. This is what I did and it worked just as I wanted. Just had to do another Find/Replace to add a couple lines of space between the strings. Thanks again!

In Notepad++:

Open Replace Dialog Ctrl + H
Change Seach Mode to Extendend
Find what: \r\n, Replace with   (one space)
Change Seach Mode to Regular expression
Find what: <End>[\s\r\n]+, Replace with <End>\r\n


P.S. Newline Escape Character detail WIKI Link
